Как подружить DearPyGUI и pygame или opengl
Я захотел написать простенький 3D редактор. Интерфейс удобнее писать с помощью dearpygui, а сам рендеринг хотелось бы выполнять на OpenGL или на pygame с контекстом OpenGL. Как можно рисовать в окне dearpygui с помощью OpenGL?
Зарание спасибо.
